# Does Free Pascal have a way to concatenate arrays?

Tags: arrays, concatenation, freepascal

Pascal apparently has string concatenation, but does it have general concatenation for any type of array?

Comment: No. Note that most of your recent questions can be found in the manual.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to search in the manual for answers to questions like this. If general concatenation existed, then it would be easy to Google "free pascal concatenate".

Comment: Try the arrays chapter in the language reference.

Comment: Which manual, there are several. Ah, the [Language Reference Guide](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/ref.html). Section: [Arrays](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu15.html#x39-430003.3.1). The document lists no concatenation method, only a copy method that could theoretically be used to write a custom concatenate function, if fpc stable had Delphi generics.

Comment: FYI: 
[Since FPC version 3.2.0](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Special:PermaLink/150650#Dynamic_Arrays_have_built_in_+_operator_support) there is a built-in _dynamic_ array concatenation operator available.

Answer (score 2):

It does not but you can make your own function i coded this in 5 minutes...i am shure there is a better method but i don't have any idea right now.

```
type
 TBArray = array of byte;  

function ConcArray(arr1,arr2:TBArray):TBArray;
begin
    SetLength(Result,Length(arr1) + Length(arr2));
    ZeroMemory(@Result[0],Length(arr1) + Length(arr2));
    CopyMemory(@Result[0],@arr1[0],Length(arr1));
    CopyMemory(@Result[Length(arr1)],@arr2[0],Length(arr2));
end;
```

Comment: That works for bytes, but how do you write ConcArray for arbitrary types (ints, shorts, arrays of arrays of bytes, etc)?

Comment: There is no general method of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? If you need to concatenate in many places, the + operator looks pretty nice IMHO.

```
  program ConCatTest;

  type
  SomeRec = record
      s: AnsiString;
      i: Longint;
  end;
  SomeArr = array of SomeRec;

    operator + (a, b: SomeArr) c: SomeArr;
    var
  i: Longint;
    begin
  SetLength(c, Length(a) + Length(b));
  for i := 0 to High(a) do
      c[i] := a[i];
  for i := 0 to High(b) do
      c[i + Length(a)] := b[i];
    end;

    var
  a1, a2, a3: SomeArr;
  i: Longint;
    begin
  SetLength(a1, 3);
  SetLength(a2, 2);
  a1[0].s := 'a';
  a1[0].i := 0;
  a1[1].s := 'a';
  a1[1].i := 1;
  a1[2].s := 'a';
  a1[2].i := 2;
  a2[0].s := 'b';
  a2[0].i := 0;
  a2[1].s := 'b';
  a2[1].i := 1;

  a3 := a1 + a2;

  for i := 0 to High(a3) do
      WriteLn(a3[i].s, a3[i].i);
  ReadLn;
  end.
```

Comment: Does this work for arrays of any type, or just `SomeRec` specifically? I'm looking for a generic way to concatenate two arrays of the same type.

Comment: It is specific for SomeRec, but all you need to do for using it for any other record/array type is to make a copy and change the first line of the operator declaration by pasting in another type. I would prefer if I could do this for all kinds of arrays at once, but this is as close as I can get.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not interested in a function for concatenating type A's together. I'm interested in a generic method for contatenating any two arrays of the same element type together, without requiring code changes.

Comment: I understand that, and I would like that too. My solution is as close as you can get AFAIK, a simple operator definition that you can adapt to another in a second by pasting in a type twice. Is this not a better solution than the ConcArray function above?